# "Having" as a gerund and possesion

Tags: word-meaning, gerunds

I have read in http://portlandenglish.edu/blog/how-to-use-being-and-having-as-gerunds/ about the use of "having".

The website describes as follows:

> - **Having a big house** costs a lot of money. [ Having a big house = subject]
> - Many people dream about **having a big house**. [ Having a big house = object of a preposition]
> - His dream is **having a big house**. [ Having a big house = subject complement]
>
> Again, we are talking about this situation or condition of having a big house.
>   To make it negative, just add “not” in front of the gerund.
>
> - **Not having servants** would be difficult if your house were so big!
> - **Having too much work** stresses him out.
> - He hates **having too much work**.
> - **Not having too much work** would make him so much happier!

My question:

"Having' always Implies or refers to 'possession' If we use "having" as a gerund where “having” can act as the subject or object in a sentence?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Can you make it clearer? "Having a big house" is a nominalisation of "(someone) has a big house", so it does refer to possession.

Comment: A person is not required as the possessor. In the sentence _"Having good brakes makes a car safe"_ there is no person involved; but _having_ in such constructions means _possessing._ Note that this is a _different_ verb than _have to,_ which connotes obligation, as in _"Having to think about this question gives me a headache."_

Comment: @Colin Fine I think I've made it clearer

Comment: @P.E Dent Do yoa mean 'having' as a gerund always acts a possession ?
I've never seen 'having to' before working as a gerund.

Comment: You've seen it now! _Have to_ is the subject of some disagreement over whether or not it is a _phrasal verb,_ but I don't see how it can be one, so it seems that the gerund _having_ denotes possession in the cases you describe **except** when it is part of _having to._

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking about *having my driveway repaved*.

The sentence above uses the gerund "having" to form a gerund phrase which is the object of the preposition "about".   The sense of "having" in this sentence is causative rather than possessive.

> *Having to repave my driveway ever couple of years* is annoying.

The sentence above uses the gerund "having" to form a gerund phrase which is the subject of the matrix clause.   The sense of "having" in this sentence can be considered as obligatory rather than possessive.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know whether the gerund "having" is only used for the possessive sense of the verb "to have".   These two counter-examples show that the possessive sense is not the only possible sense for the gerund in question.

Answer (score 1):

> "Having' always Implies or refers to 'possession' If we use "having" as a gerund where “having” can act as the subject or object in a sentence?

No, all the alternate meanings and phrasal variations of *have* work as gerunds.

> Having your employees well trained is a good thing to do. (alternate meaning of *have*)
>
> Having to go to court made John have to line up a ride. (phrasal variation *have to X*)

Also you can do this:

> The machine is broken.  Having said that, you can still use it if you be careful.